# Not able to export image using bokeh/holoviews

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, bokeh, geckodriver, holoviews

I initially had installed :-

`conda install selenium geckodriver firefox -c conda-forge` from bokeh documentation page on anaconda prompt and *I was able to export image* as png & open image as URL on `Internet Explorer`.
All of a sudden today I get this error :-

`RuntimeError: Neither firefox and geckodriver nor a variant of chromium browser and chromedriver are available on system PATH. You can install the former with 'conda install -c conda-forge firefox geckodriver'.`  on Spyder
I checked the `path` and geckodriver is very much in the `path` it was initially.(`C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs\geckodriver-0.27.0-h33f27b4_0\Scripts\geckodriver.exe')

I'm not able to understand why suddenly it stopped working, tried a few fixes from other SO answers like installing chromium driver :-
`conda install -c conda-forge python-chromedriver-binary` in anaconda prompt

```
`from selenium.webdriver import Chrome,ChromeOptions
 options=ChromeOptions()
 options.add_argument('--headless')
my_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs\python-chromedriver-binary-87.0.4280.20.0-py38h32f6830_0\Lib\site-packages\chromedriver_binary\chromedriver.exe',options=options)`
```

This gives me :-

`SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87 Current browser version is 83.0.4103.116 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` error.

I am not allowed to manually download a driver from the website to suit the version/update chrome browser. So `chrome` driver is ruled out.
I have only `IE` and `Chrome` browsers installed,I want to know why my initial method which opens image in `IE` is not working anymore,and how to make it work again.

P.S :- I tried updating `geckodriver` (ran the same `conda install selenium geckodriver firefox -c conda-forge` again and geckodriver was updated )and `Selenium` but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Could you show us the Code you use yo open geckodriver?

Comment: There is no need to open geckodriver just `from bokeh.io import show,export_png` thi import done used to work until yesterday.As it didnt work I tried setting webdriver path explicitly to initiate

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs\geckodriver-0.27.0-h33f27b4_0\Scripts\geckodriver.exe')`. Tried this now after you said and it says `SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome procedure you used worked for me by using python not on path
that is regular pip install and your ide of choice.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).